# How to inherit abstract class with PyCharm

Tags: python, oop, pycharm

I wrote a code in Python IDLE with one abstract class and one class that inherit that abstract class *(both classes are in the same folder). It works great.
I want to copy and paste that code to PyCharm. I made two cards, one with abstract class and one with class that inherit that class but I get this error:

```
    class Swords(Weapon):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Im confused because I didnt change anything in my code. This is the code

**First Card: Weapon**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Weapon(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

**Second Card: Sword**

```
import Weapon


class Swords(Weapon):

    def __init__(self, name, attack_points, price):
        super().__init__(name)

        self.attack_points = attack_points
        self.price = price

    def info(self):
        info = self.name + " is attack-weapon that increases attack points!"
        return info

    def __str__(self):
        return "Sword name: {}\nSword attack: +{}\nSword price: {}\n".format(self.name,
                                                                             self.attack_points,
                                                                             self.price)


Elf_Sword = Swords("Elf Sword", 1, 50)
Fire_Sword = Swords("Fire Sword", 2, 80)
Space_Sword = Swords("Space Sword", 3, 120)


print(Elf_Sword)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have your `Weapon` class in a module called `Weapon.py`, and you're just importing the module, not the class.

Whether or not it's an ABC doesn't matter here.

As a general naming rule of thumb,

- Modules should, in general, be lowercase
- Classes should be in PascalCase and singular

## weapon.py

```
class Weapon:
    pass
```

## sword.py

```
from weapon import Weapon

class Sword(Weapon):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant import classes. You have to import modules, or classes from those modules.

In your case, the syntax is

```
from file_where_weapon_is import Weapon
```